# Requests, responses and computing their average and standard deviation

Tags: performance-testing

I need to do a performance test where I have to send millions of Url requests to the Server over a period of time and capture all their responses. From the responses, I need to calculate their average response times and standard deviation (this can be done using spreadsheet but when it comes to millions of Urls, it is cumbersome). What is the best possible way to test this performance scenario. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My environment is as below :

- NLBs to route the requests to resolvers.
- linux servers as our core resolvers.
- Windows machines are used for clients. Requests generated by these machines.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the fastest and the easiest way would be using a load testing tool, i.e. [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) which is free, open source and doesn't require any extra knowledge.

URLs can be defined either using [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) or JMeter can be configured to act like a "crawler" via [HTML Link Parser](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTML_Link_Parser)

Once your test is finished you can visualize results using i.e. [Summary Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report) listener which has average response time, standard deviation and some other "interesting" metrics:

[image: JMeter Summary Report]

JMeter can be run in [Distributed Mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) so you can run a JMeter instance per Windows machine and results will be aggregated on a master node.

Check out [JMeter Academy](https://www.blazemeter.com/jmeter-tutorial) to get ramped up on the tool in just few hours (if not minutes)

Comment: Thank you Dmitri, I am trying on it.